# XMM register instructions and their c equivalents

Tags: x86, float

I'm trying to convert some x86 assembly back into C++, and I cannot figure out how this set of instructions was originally written.

```
movd xmm0,eax ; byte read from device '0x04'
cvtdq2pd xmm0,xmm0 ; convert packed to double?
shr eax,0x1F ; highest bit
addsd xmm0,qword ptr ds:[eax*8+0x4F6CC0] ; global [0, 4294967296] if I read it right
cvtpd2ps xmm0,xmm0 ; double to packed?
movss dword ptr ds:[ebx+0x34],xmm0 ; store the result
```

I've tried various forms of casting `float` and `double` to other data types on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) but I cannot find anything that reproduces the `cvtdq2pd` and `cvtpd2ps` instructions.

What would the above code look like in c/c++ and what is the resulting data type?

Comment: I'd guess the first four lines are loading an unsigned 32-bit value into a double: if cvtdq2pd treats the input as signed then you'd need to add 1<<32 to correct the output if the top bit of the input is set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You likely won't get an exact reproduction because `cvtdq2pd` takes the lower 64 bits of the second operand but since we're limited to 32 bits because we're using `eax` here, there are probably better(?) instructions to use.

`cvtsi2sd xmm0, eax`

will do the same thing as

`movd xmm0,eax`

`cvtdq2pd xmm0,xmm0`

See here https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTDQ2PD.html & https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html

So really what it's doing is converting a 32 bit **signed** integer value into a double precision floating point.

---

Onto your actual question:

`cvtpd2ps xmm0,xmm0 ; double to packed?`

> CVTPD2PS xmm1, xmm2/m128
>
> Convert two packed double-precision floating-point values in xmm2/mem to two single-precision floating-point values in xmm1.

This will pack the two double precision floats at `xmm0[0:63]` & `xmm0[64:127]` into the lower 64 bits of `xmm0`, converting them from double to single precision floating point values (`xmm0[0:31]` & `xmm0[32:63]`).

Ref: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPD2PS.html

So if the lower 64 bits of `xmm0` represented a `double`, it's now been converted to a 32 bit float, which now sits in the lower 32 bits of `xmm0`.

`movss dword ptr ds:[ebx+0x34],xmm0`

> MOVSS xmm2/m32, xmm1
>
> Move scalar single-precision floating-point value from xmm1 register to xmm2/m32.

Now stores the 4 byte result from `xmm0[0:31]` into `[ebx+0x34]`, which we know is a single precision `float` from the result of the `cvtpd2ps` operation.

So the result of this operation is a 32 bit `float`.

Ref: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSS.html

---

This code here should be a reasonable approximation. [In Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/0mi2_9) it gives me similar assembly to what you have.

```
double* d_arr = (double*)0x4F6CC0;

int main() {

    int in = 4;
    int signbit = ((unsigned int)in >> 31);
    float result = *(double*)(d_arr + signbit) + in;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Conclusion:

`cvtdq2pd` & `cvtpd2ps` are too powerful for what's actually being calculated here. Unless I'm reading this totally wrong, the upper 64 bits of `xmm0` are never relevant to the result.

Disclaimer:

I've never used floating point assembly before. I just looked up the docs now. I could be missing something.